# Sending props to child of child component

Tags: reactjs

I can't to send props from the parent component two levels down, to a child of a child component. I'm trying to send userInput.

Parent:

```
function App() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header userInput={userInput} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
      <MainContainer userInput={userInput} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Middle component:

```
const MainContainer = (userInput, setUserInput) => {
  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <AlbumContainer userInput={userInput} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Final component:

```
const AlbumContainer = ({ userInput, setUserInput }) => {
  return (
    <div className="album-container">
      <h1>{userInput}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are declaring and accessing your props incorrectly on the two child components. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 2):

Please use this for `MainContainer` Component. You did not destructuring for `MainContainer` Component. That's why it was not working.

```
const MainContainer = ({userInput, setUserInput}) => {
  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <AlbumContainer userInput={userInput} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
    </div>
  );
};
```